# More redundant tags - biochemistry and chemical-biology

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[biochemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biochemistry) and [chemical-biology](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemical-biology) seem to be the same. Additionally there are 25 questions which have both tags, which seems redundant. Should they be merged?

Comment: The difference between the field of study they represent are subtle yet distinct.  See: http://www.brandeis.edu/departments/chemistry/docs/Chemical%20Biology.pdf

Comment: @LordStryker Perhaps you could write up a better tag wiki and excerpt for it. At the moment they appear to be exactly the same.

Comment: @Bon in fact, I've tried to come up with tag wikis that differentiate between them. . . But I've failed and failed and failed. The two aren't the same IMO.

Comment: I consider biochemistry to be the study of the chemistry of biological systems, where chemical biology is using the tools of chemistry to solve biological problems. Or perhaps it is the newest iteration of the physical chemistry / chemical physics problem.

Comment: I agree with @BenNorris and changed chemical-biology to reflect that.

Comment: And I reviewed and approved your edit @jerepierre.

Answer (score 4):

I think this issue should be revisited. While I can see there being a reasonable distinction between the two, the use of the chemical-biology tag hasn't really fit its short tag description and it still has no tag wiki. Most of the questions tagged with it seem to fall under two categories (I don't have hard data, but this is my impression looking through the first few pages):

1. More appropriately tagged biochemistry
2. Tagged with both biochemistry and chemical-biology (and usually more appropriately biochemistry based on the wiki description).

If it isn't just going to be made a synonym, I think the wiki needs to fleshed out and questions that shouldn't have chemical-biology should have it swapped for the appropriate tag or removed.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up again. I agree that the usage is generally inconsistent, probably because most people do not know the difference. However, I am actually going to outright veto the possibility of making these a synonym; they are not the same at all. I much prefer the tougher, but ultimately correct, option of doing up the tag wiki and retagging questions appropriately.